# Google Analytics from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My customer wants to track backend user's activity using google-analytics. He wants me to insert UserId in every URL of the backend. Backend is ASP.NET MVC3 and I tried to use routing for this purpose but without any luck.

I thought about more intellegent way to satisfy his need. So I'm thinking about calling google-analytics api from the server-side.

Is there an ability to do all that `ga.js` does but from c#?

**Updated:**
Customer wants to track user's activity using Google Analytics.
He wants me to add ?userId= to all links in backend.
So if I had /Category/Edit/123 now I have to change it to /Category/Edit/123?userId=456
Then I put ga.js to every page and customer tracks user's (456) activity.

I find the idea of using Google Analytics this way sucks but I have to implement some solution. The only thing I want is not to change urls but act with Google Analytics API from the server side.

Comment: *backend user's activity using google-analytics*? Eh?

Comment: I'd like not to use GA but for now I have to estimate the implementation for it and adding UserId is sucks. Customer wants it.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your trying to ask. It makes no sense. Can you try an clarify somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is what think I actually needed:

1) Create Custim Dimension in Google Analytics console
Admin -> Custom Definitions -> Custom Dimensions -> New Custom Dimension -> userId

2) Modify my Google Analytics javascript and insert

```
var userId = @User.Id;
ga('set', 'dimension1', userId);
```

before ga("send", "pageview");

**OR**

use this solution

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id?hl=en